# parse complex xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have one xml file whose structure is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EM>
   <DEFAULT>
      <Channel1>
         <CONFIG_PARAM>
            <Item name="line" value="0" />
            <Item name="ULimt" value="0" />
            <Item name="LLimit" value="0" />
            <Item name="CLabel" value="0" />
         </CONFIG_PARAM>
      </Channel1>
      <Channel2>
         <CONFIG_PARAM>
            <Item name="line" value="0" />
            <Item name="ULimt" value="0" />
            <Item name="LLimit" value="0" />
            <Item name="CLabel" value="1" />
         </CONFIG_PARAM>
      </Channel2>
      <CONFIG_PARAM>
         <Item name="Frequency" value="50" />
         <Item name="EMark" value="2" />
         <Item name="Lang" value="LANG_ENG" />
         <Item name="ID" value="111111111111111111111111111" />
         <Item name="AMethod" value="AUC_CM_ERROR" />
         <Item name="AValue" value="0" />
      </CONFIG_PARAM>
   </DEFAULT>
   <UPDATED>
      <Channel1>
         <CONFIG_PARAM>
            <Item name="line" value="0" />
            <Item name="ULimt" value="0" />
            <Item name="LLimit" value="0" />
            <Item name="CLabel" value="0" />
         </CONFIG_PARAM>
      </Channel1>
      <Channel2>
         <CONFIG_PARAM>
            <Item name="line" value="0" />
            <Item name="ULimt" value="0" />
            <Item name="LLimit" value="0" />
            <Item name="CLabel" value="1" />
         </CONFIG_PARAM>
      </Channel2>
      <CONFIG_PARAM>
         <Item name="Frequency" value="50" />
         <Item name="EMark" value="2" />
         <Item name="Lang" value="LANG_ENG" />
         <Item name="ID" value="111111111111111111111111111" />
         <Item name="AMethod" value="AUC_CM_ERROR" />
         <Item name="AValue" value="0" />
      </CONFIG_PARAM>
   </UPDATED>
</EM>
```

I have DEFAULT and UPDATED two tag. Inside that I have channel1, channel2 and CONFIG_PARAM tag.
My requirement is like this:

1. In DEFAULT tag all the value are default value. and UPDATED tag  have latest updated value when user are performing some operation.

i want to create property like this:

```
default.Channel1
default.Channl2
default.Config_param
```

same way for UPDATED tag:

```
updated.Channel1
updated.Channel2
updated.config_param
```

for example like this i want to create proprty:

```
private List<ParameterNode> channel1 = new List<ParameterNode>();
public List<ParameterNode> Channel1
{
    get
    {
        return this.channel1;
    }
}
```

Please tell me how can I create property.

P.S: I have written this code to get the value:

```
// find the channel1 element and load the Item
XmlElement channel1Element = GetUniqueElement(doc.DocumentElement, "Channel1");
if (channel1Element != null)
    this.channel1 = ConfigParameterNode.LoadItems(channel1Element);

private static XmlElement GetUniqueElement(XmlNode parent, string name)
{
    XmlElement result = null;

    foreach (XmlNode node in parent.ChildNodes)
    {
    XmlElement element = node as XmlElement;
    if (element == null)
        continue;
    if (element.Name != name)
        continue;

    result = element;
    }

    return result;
}
internal static List<ParameterNode> LoadItems(XmlElement parent)
{
    List<ParameterNode> result = new List<ParameterNode>();

    // go through all the children and find the Item elements
    foreach (XmlNode child in parent.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (child.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in child.ChildNodes)
            {
                // is it an element
                XmlElement element = node as XmlElement;
                if (element == null)
                    continue;


                // yes, so add it if it's an Item element
                if (element.LocalName == "Item")
                    result.Add(new ParameterNode(element));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // is it an element
            XmlElement element = child as XmlElement;
            if (element == null)
                continue;


            // yes, so add it if it's an Item element
            if (element.LocalName == "Item")
                result.Add(new ParameterNode(element));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Please tell me how can I change my code so that I can create property default.Channel1, default.Channel2 and default.config_param.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer of this question.

XmlElement defElement = GetUniqueElement(doc.DocumentElement, "DEFAULT");

after that pass this defElement to other method. I this Create property for default parameter.